# nil resultURL after successfully posting with FBWebDialogs (Facebook SDK 3.5)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm integrating **Facebook** on my application to share links of websites. I'm using the Feed Dialog to accomplish this and I'm following this tutorial:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/.

I've managed to login and post to Facebook but I wanted to add a message when the post was successful. The tutorial has this built in, but every time I post, I see "*User canceled story publishing.*" in the Log which is the message that is displayed when the user clicks on cancel. Besides I've confirmed with the debugger that the param `resultURL` received by the handler is always nil even on successful posts.

At first I though it was a configuration issue in my `Facebook App`, but I decided to make a test. I opened the `RPSSample` that comes with the framework, added a completion handler to the `presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession` call in the `clickInviteFriends` method in the `RPSFriendsViewController.m` view controller and I was getting a nil `resultURL` on successful posts there too.

I'm I missing something?

I know the 3.5 SDK version is very new, but according to the documentation I should be getting a valid `resultURL` param after posting through a *Facebook Web Dialog* so I'm not sure if it's a bug or if I'm missing some callback or handler somewhere.

Just in case, this is my call to the *Feed Web Dialog*. It has minor changes compared to the one that comes in the tutorial (it's actually simpler)

```
- (void)publish: (EntityToShare *)entityToShare {
NSMutableDictionary *params =
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 entityToShare.link, @"link",
 nil];

// Invoke the dialog
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                       parameters:params
                                          handler:
 ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         // Error launching the dialog or publishing a story.
         NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
     } else {
         if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
             // User clicked the "x" icon
             NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
         } else {
             // Handle the publish feed callback
             NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
             if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {
                 // User clicked the Cancel button
                 NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
             } else {
                 // User clicked the Share button
                 NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                  @"Posted story, id: %@",
                                  [urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]];
                 NSLog(@"%@", msg);
                 // Show the result in an alert
                 [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result"
                                             message:msg
                                            delegate:nil
                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                                   otherButtonTitles:nil]
                  show];
             }
         }
     }
 }];
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have a fix for this in place and will be pushed out soon.

Edited:

This has now been fixed in the SDK release 3.5.1
Check it out here: https://developers.facebook.com/ios/

Comment: I'm having the same problem as Diego. When will you expect to have it fixed?

Comment: Great! Thanks for answering so quickly. This was driving me crazy. So, is this a server issue or is there something wrong with the SDK?

Comment: I am waiting for this so urgent, is it only an api bug that will not affect my native code?

Comment: Edited my response. Was a bug in the SDK. We've pushed out the fix.

Comment: I am using the new sdk 3.7 and i am still having the same issue